# Which 'finger' was BB-8 sticking up?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, bb-8

At one point in *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, Finn and BB-8 are talking.  Finn gives BB-8 a thumbs-up. In return, BB-8 extends a little lit welding torch. I've heard two different understandings of BB-8's gesture:

1. It was a thumbs-up, agreeing with Finn.
2. It was a middle finger, as BB-8 disagreed with Finn.

Which is the accurate analysis?

Comment: The question, while goofy, doesn't really deserve downvotes IMO. Any good reason for the vote, downvoters?

Comment: I didn't downvote.  I look forward to the near future when we'll be able to have clips of TFA to link to, so we can better speculate on the answer.

Comment: I've actually seen a lot of speculation on other websites as to what he was doing, it's obviously a thumbs up, but a lot of people aren't getting that. It's a good question.

Comment: @Mikey - You'll be pleased to learn that that clip is already available, as part of the latest trailer; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cTjX1WOMhw

Comment: The first time I saw it, I totally thought it was a middle finger. After two more viewings and hearing everyone else’s opinion, I think it was a thumbs up too. I think either interpretation kind of works, but thumbs up seems more in keeping with BB-8’s character.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I didn't even consider the middle-finger possibility until I saw this question, so it goes both ways.

Comment: Context feels like a thumbs up to me, but I can see how you might misread the context.

Comment: Is lighting a cigarette lighter at a concert passe? Clearly it was meant as a positive gesture.

Comment: I definitely thought it was a middle finger, along with a thinly-veiled threat, since it's a blow-torch.  Like "Just try and cross me - I will burn your hand off!"  A little disappointing if it wasn't intended that way...

Comment: I'm reasonably sure it was a kindhearted gesture, I've read BB-88 was designed to be cute.

Comment: I like the way it could be read both ways. Or 'mess this up, I will burn you!' :)

Comment: Evidence that the middle finger controversy is real - a poll of 2,700 (not quite randomly selected) twitter users showed that over one third of them thought it was a middle finger: https://twitter.com/leyawn/status/685642947732344832

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Not so clear.  The end of the noise he makes could be interpreted as making his whole noise a scowl.  I thought Finn was seeking support, and BB8's middle finger was "no, I'm totally not on your side.  Your idea should be burnt up."  The flame rather cemented that

Comment: Anyone with a modicum of exposure to character profiling and body behavior will tell you it's a thumbs up. It's clear that BB-8 is mimicking the positively reinforcing behavior displayed by Finn after they reach a newfound level of trust.

Comment: It's clearly a thumbs up. Everyone who was watching it in the cinema when I went to see it got it straight away.

Comment: Regardless of the intent of the creators, it should be said that both interpretations are valid. The character has motivations in the moment that would convince a viewer of one gesture or the other.

Comment: I've watched the movie twice and both times, I thought it was a raised middle-finger. I find it more satisfying, as it gives BB-8 a real personality, rather than just making him a cutesy cuddly toy. And it fits the situation better, IMO. Let's review: Finn was basically emotionally blackmailing the little droid into something it was reluctant to do. Flipping the bird is a very natural response in this situation. But I can understand why some would "prefer" to see it as a thumbs up. My theory is that those who see it as a thumbs up are the same people who are fine with Greedo shooting first. :)

Comment: While the OP asks for an analysis, both views are valid (IMO, the source their DVs). Asking only for the creators intent would remove its POB status.

Comment: HA! Someone flagged this as "primarily opinion-based". Ridiculous.

Comment: @maguirenumber6: “Everyone who was watching it in the cinema when I went to see it got it straight away.” It was very canny of you to take a poll before everyone left.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Why thank you :-)

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Some Industrial Light and Magic people discussed the process behind animating that moment, in [an interview](http://www.mtv.com/news/2727582/bb-8-thumbs-up-star-wars/) with MTV:

> “We did several different prototype ideas of what that could look like, and we had various amounts of metal and plastic on there,” added Patrick Tubach, another ILM visual effects supervisor for the film. “One of the difficult things with animating something like that is you have to be very careful that it doesn’t look like he’s giving you some *other* sort of gesture! We moved all the pieces around to make sure it was very clearly a thumbs up over any other kind of ’salute.'”

So it is meant to be a thumbs up.

Comment: Extended discussion on self answers had been removed.  Please continue in [chat] if you wish to continue.

Comment: I just assumed it was a shout-out to Stan Laurel of Laurel & Hardy. Stan had a "magic lighter" where he could generate a small flame from his thumb. (Of course when Hardy managed to do it, he burned his thumb). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDrYVzb5KAU

Answer (score 112):

The [novelisation of the film](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel)) explicitly states that it is indeed intended to be a "thumbs-up" from BB-8

> *“Doing the best I can down here.” Rey vanished again. As soon as she
> was out of sight, the grateful Finn gave BB-8 a thumbs-up. The droid
> responded by shooting out a welding torch **in imitation of the human’s
> gesture.***

As does the [2017 Star Wars Annual](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Annual_2017)

[image]
<sub><sup>"*After BB-8 reveals the location of the Resistance base, both exchange
a thumbs-up*."</sup></sub>

As does the [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know, Updated and Expanded](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know,_Updated_and_Expanded) edition

[image]
<sub><sup>"*Using his welding torch to give a thumbs up*"</sup></sub>

---

The [original screenplay](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html) is slightly more ambiguous, but the intention seems pretty clear

> **Finn:** *Yeah, the Ileenium system, that's the one -- get us there as fast as you
> can.*
>
> A smiling Finn gives BB-8 a THUMBS UP. BB-8 quickly extends his
> WELDING TORCH and TURNS IT UPWARD, then retracts it.

[image]

The film's special effects master, Neal Scanlan, explicitly confirmed in an interview with MTV.com that it was intended to be a 'thumbs up'.

> *"I think the reaction that BB-8 has to Finn would have been a
> practical effect that we shot on the Milennium Falcon, but the
> reaction to the thumbs up is something that definitely came later in
> the day," Scanlan said.*
>
> *"**That thumbs up moment is exactly that**," confirmed Guyett. "I think
> it’s a real BB-8 and then we inserted a CG panel and its arm that came
> out. So all of his tools, if you like, when he fires his wires and he
> does that stuff, that’s sort of digital CG."*
>
> <sub><sup>[‘STAR WARS’: BB-8’S THUMBS UP MOMENT ALMOST DIDN’T HAPPEN](http://www.mtv.com/news/2727582/bb-8-thumbs-up-star-wars/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Great GIF, I can see why there's confusion... He seems to "flip" the thumbs up.

Comment: @LindseyD - Cheers. I made the gif myself.

Comment: The more I see it the more it looks like the bird.

Comment: That gif gets funnier the more you watch it :,)

Comment: @LindseyD he does from this angle but if you look closely, the entire arm rotates counter clockwise (from our view)

Answer (score 1):

I always thought it was a thumbs up. BB-8 thinks that Finn is honest about who he is, and BB-8 respects his honesty somehow and decides he may be a good guy after all.

Comment: Any evidence of this?